# Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'] was not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

Gradle command throwing below Exception:

Where:
Build file '/path_to_project_gradle/build.gradle' line: 21

- What went wrong:
  *Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:*
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

> Configuration :

**JAVA Configuration :** 
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

[image: Gradle configuration]

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: It would definitely help to show content of build.gradle.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to internet?

Comment: @MehrajMalik, Yes connected to the internet.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace obtained by running your command with `-s`

Comment: @All, solved this issue. This issue because of multiple gradle installations in my ubuntu machine. Instead of downloading dependencies in my project gradle folder, the dependencies downloading to the system gradle directory. I uninstalled my system gradle and tried using with my project gradle wrapper, It's working now. Thanks for your response..

Answer (score 6):

You should toggle offline mode

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Or, in the IntelliJ, you can choose to use "use local gradle distribution" then uncheck the "offline work" in the next session.